# Batch file execution using C# process

Tags: c#, batch-file, stdout

I am trying to figure out a way to run a bat file using c# process

starttest.bat file is as below

```
@echo off

echo Started testing
path\to\my\app.exe [args]
echo Testing finished
```

When I run this from command line using

```
starttest.bat
```

I get the following output

> Started testing
>
> Total TestCases: 2 Passed: 1 Failed: 1 NotTested: 0
>
> Total TestScenarios: 0 Passed: 0 Failed: 0 NotTested: 0 exit
>
> Testing finished

But when i try to run this bat file using c# process in .net core, I get the following

> Started testing
>   Testing finished

The output from myapp.exe is not received in standard output event

```
class BatExec
{
    static Process proc = new Process();

    public static void Execute()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("starttest.bat");


        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

        // Called when Std Out is written to by the process
        proc.OutputDataReceived += PrintData;

        // Called when Std Err is written to by the process
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += PrintData;

        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintData(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BatExec.Execute();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why introduce a command processor and a batch file when you can just run the other program directly yourself?

Comment: this is just a simplified version of bat file, there are multiple commands which needs to be executed.

Comment: how does the app.exe write to stdout? is it you own app? obviously a testrunner?

Comment: checked the your code with e.g. `powercgf /lastwake` inside a .bat and works like you expect. Usually you have to run the batch files as a parameter of cmd.exe like in scheduled jobs, so I am bit wondering that you can run the batch at all (as it implicitly starts cmd.exe as host)

Comment: If you are trying to handle command line arguments when executing app.exe then it won't work because the C# code that you have displayed does not look as though it is able to handle command line arguments